# DD4T: How to Sort Component list from FindComponents by Field

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, api

I'm trying to sort the `IComponent` list by a "Field Value" in the component using `ExtendedQueryParameters`, but by default the `QuerySortField` is assigned with default value. Help me to sort with other fields in the component.

Example, I want to sort the list by date field in the component.

How can I change this  **QuerySortField**,

```
public ExtendedQueryParameters()
{
    // Default all parameters
    QuerySchemas = new string[]{};
    MetaQueryValues = new List<MetaQueryItem>();
    MetaQueryLogic = QueryLogic.AllCriteriaMatch;

    KeywordValues = new List<KeywordItem>();
    KeywordQueryLogic = QueryLogic.AllCriteriaMatch;

    LastPublishedDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    **QuerySortField = "ItemTitle";**
    SortType = MetaSortFieldType.STRING;
    SortType = MetaSortFieldType.DATETIME;
    QuerySortOrder = MetaQueryOrder.Ascending;
    MaximumComponents = int.MaxValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QuerySortField` is public property, you can update the value.

but i think you can have only fields of type `SortColumn`(ItemCreationDate, ItemMajorVersion, many more) from `Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.SortParameter`class and Meta data Field of your component, if date field in your question is meta datafield you can get result as per your requirement, but with non-metaField its not possible. You can also update that field to MetaData field.

```
var parameters = new ExtendedQueryParameters();
parameters.QuerySortField = "YourcustomMetaField"; 
parameters.SortType = ExtendedQueryParameters.MetaSortFieldType.DATETIME; parameters.PublicationId = publicationID; 
parameters.QuerySchemas = new[] { schemaId }; 
parameters.FindComponents(queryparameters);
```

you can also try CD API

```
var publicationCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(publicationId);
var itemScemaCriteria = new ItemSchemaCriteria(SchemaTcmUri.ItemId);
var customMetaKeyCriteria = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("MetaIssueDate", Criteria.Equal);
Criteria[] finalCriteria = { publicationCriteria, itemScemaCriteria, customMetaKeyCriteria};
var query = new Query(CriteriaFactory.And(finalCriteria));
var customMetaKeyColumnDate = new CustomMetaKeyColumn("MetaIssueDate", MetadataType.DATE);
var sortParameter = new SortParameter(customMetaKeyColumnDate, SortParameter.Descending);
query.AddSorting(sortParameter);
var result = query.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: am able get the sort by the Metadata field but i want this to combine with Keyword filter and Mate data sort. below code is giving error.                                 var queryParameters = new ExtendedQueryParameters();
            string[] schemas = { SchemaUri };
            queryParameters.QuerySchemas = schemas;
            queryParameters.PublicationId = ID;
            queryParameters.KeywordValues = keys;                         queryParameters.QuerySortField = "date";
      queryParameters.SortType =ExtendedQueryParameters.MetaSortFieldType.DATETIME; FindComponents(queryParameters)

Comment: is this keyword part of metadata?

Comment: keywords are not part of Metadata; if this can be resolved by moving to meta i can move it. please provide more details on the code for keyword filter in metadata..

Comment: if its part of  metadata, normal metadata query should work just provide the "xmlname" of that metafield in the  query

Comment: any other way if the keyword is not in meta data...